# No notifications?

Tags: support, notifications

On other SE sites, I receive a notification if someone comments on a Q/A I asked, answered, or commented on, or votes up a comment I made.

However, on the Eng Beta, I have only been receiving notifications for upvotes to Q/As, or for answers to a question I asked.

Is there a bug? Is this a feature that needs to be turned on? Am I doing something wrong?

Also: I also received a few upvotes to a Q on meta.engineering, but did not receive any notification of this, either.

To be clear: all of this activity appears in the dropdown menu. But there is no notification of "unread" activity like I get on, for example, Stackoverflow.

Comment: You wouldn't get a notification about votes on your meta posts, since they don't affect your reputation. (Your rep on meta just mirrors your main site rep.) Did you get a notification for this comment?

Comment: Yes! Bizarre. I actually may have gotten some earlier today as well (can't remember for sure), but I definitely didn't get them for several days prior.

Comment: Huh. Try and keep note going forward of what specific events did and didn't trigger notifications if you're still seeing the weird behavior.

Comment: No problems so far today. The problem seemed to disappear when the site moved out of private beta yesterday.

Comment: abby: I did not receive a notification of [this reply](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-do-i-calculate-the-forces-on-a-desk-and-its-legs#comment753_370) to a comment I made. The reply is also not listed in my dropdown menu on the control panel.

Comment: Aha! That comment didn't @-mention you by name, and since you weren't the owner of the post, you wouldn't have gotten a notification. You get notifications on *every* comment on your own post, and only the ones that @-mention you on others' posts.

Comment: ...is that the way things work on the other SE sites as well? For some reason I think I recall getting notified of any replay to a comment on, say, Stackoverflow. I guess I could be wrong though.

Comment: That should be how it works, but... I just got notified about your most recent comment, which did not @-mention me. I'll see if I can dig up the docs on how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. So.

[Here's the lowdown on how comment notifications work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/165581).

This passage is relevant to the mystery we encountered in [our comment thread above](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/no-notifications?noredirect=1#comment231_119):

> Note if a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is not included.

Read up on that MSE post -- this is how it should be working on all Q&A sites, Engineering included. Let me know if you're noticing any behavior that's not listed in there.

From your post:

> On other SE sites, I receive a notification if someone comments on a Q/A I asked, answered, or commented on, or votes up a comment I made.

You shouldn't be receiving notifications for comment upvotes. We don't send those on any site.

> Also: I also received a few upvotes to a Q on meta.engineering, but did not receive any notification of this, either.

Voting on per-site metas doesn't change your reputation, since your meta rep mirrors your main site rep. This means meta votes don't trigger green rep notifications like votes do on main sites.

Comment: That's extremely helpful! I probably am imagining notifications from comment upvotes, then. I'll pay more attention from now on (for some reason it's hard to remember what, exactly, I was notified about).